# In JS which one makes sense: searching for a value in object collection by foreach vs keeping multiple collections with different keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on some kind of 1:1 chat system, the environment is Node.JS
For each country, there is a country room (lobby), for each socket client there is a js class/object is being created and each object is in a list with their unique user id.

This unique id is preserved even users logged in from different browser tabs etc..

Each object stored in collections like: "connections" (all of them), "operators"(only operators), "{countryISO}_clients" (users) and the reference key is their unique id.

In some circumstances, I need to access these connections by their socket ids.
At this point, I can think of 2 resolutions.

1. Using a for each loop to find the desired object
2. Creating another collection, this time instead of unique id use socket id (or something else.)

Which one makes sense? Because in JS since this collection will be a reference list instead of a copy, it feels like it makes sense (and beautiful looking) but I can't be sure. Which one is expensive in memory/performance terms?

I can't make thorough tests since I don't know how to create dummy (simultaneous) socket connections.

Expected connected socket client count: 300 - 1000 (depends on the time of the day)

e.g. user:

```
"qk32d2k":{
 "uid":"qk32d2k",
 "name":"Josh",
 "socket":"{socket.io's socket reference}",
 "role":"user",
 "rooms":["room1"],
 "socketids":["sid1"]
 "country":"us",
 ...
 info:() => { return gatherSomeData(); },
 update:(obj) => { return updateSomeData(obj); },
 send:(data)=>{ /*send data to this user*/ }
}
```

e.g. Countries collection:

```
{
 us:{
  "qk32d2k":{"object above."}
  "l33t71":{"another user object."}
 },

 ca:{
  "asd231":{"other user object."}
 }
}
```

Comment: *In some circumstances,* how often? How many sockets are there in the best/average/worst case?

Comment: What makes the most sense to me is using `Array.prototype.find`; as far as optimal performance, try using data structures that have optimal time complexity on look ups (like a BST).

Comment: I feel like _most_ of the time, if you are carrying around multiple copies of the same data then there is something wrong with the underlying data structure.

Comment: @JonasWilms Sorry, I forgot to mention, question updated accordingly. Once the project is live in the first month around 100, then expected numbers between 300-1k

Comment: @nurdyguy You're absolutely right, but you can think this question out of context and I was thinking instead of carrying the same data creating another reference table. Like a database table with multiple indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pick Simple Design First that Optimizes for Most Common Access**

There is no ideal answer here in the absolute.  CPUs are wicked fast these days, so if I were you I'd start out with one simple mechanism of storing the sockets that you can access both ways you want, even if one way is kind of a brute force search.  Pick the data structure that optimizes the access mechanism that you expect to be either most common or most sensitive to performance.

So, if you are going to be looking up by userID the most, then I'd probably store the sockets in a `Map` object with the userID as the key.  That will give you fast, optimized access to get the socket for a given userID.

For finding a socket by some other property of the socket, you will just iterate the `Map` item by item until you find the desired match on some other socket property.  I'd probably use a `for/of` loop because it's both fast and easy to bail out of the loop when you've found your match (something you can't do on a `Map` or `Array` object with `.forEach()`).  You can obviously make yourself a little utility function or method that will do the brute force lookup for you and that will allow you to modify the implementation later without changing much calling code.

**Measure and Add Further Optimization Later (if data shows you need to)**

Then, once you get up to scale (or simulated scale in pre-production test), you take a look at the performance of your system.  If you have loads of room to spare, you're done - no need to look further.  If you have some operations that are slower than desired or higher than desired CPU usage, then you profile your system and find out where the time is going.  It's most likely  that your performance bottlenecks will be elsewhere in your system and you can then concentrate on those aspects of the system.  If, in your profiling, you find that the linear lookup to find the desired socket is causing some of your slow-down, then you can make a second parallel lookup Map with the socketID as the key in order to optimize that type of lookup.

But, I would not recommend doing this until you've actually shown that it is an issue.  Premature optimization before you have actual metrics that prove it's worth optimizing something just add complexity to a program without any proof that it is required or even anywhere close to a meaningful bottleneck in your system.  Our intuition about what the bottlenecks are is often way, way off.  For that reasons, I tend to pick an intelligent first design that is relatively simple to implement, maintain and use and then, only when we have real usage data by which we can measure actual performance metrics would I spend more time optimizing it or tweaking it or making it more complicated in order to make it faster.

**Encapsulate the Implementation in Class**

If you encapsulate all operations here in a class:

1. Adding a socket to the data structure.
2. Removing a socket from the data structure.
3. Looking up by userID
4. Looking up by socketID
5. Any other access to the data structure

Then, all calling code will access this data structure via the class and you can tweak the implementation some time in the future (to optimize based on data) without having to modify any of the calling code.   This type of encapsulation can be very useful if you suspect future modifications or change of modifications to the way the data is stored or accessed.

**If You're Still Worried, Design a Quick Bench Measurement**

I created a quick snippet that tests how long a brute force lookup is in a 1000 element `Map` object (when you want to find it by something other than what the key is) and compared it to an indexed lookup.

On my computer, a brute force lookup (non-indexed lookup) takes about 0.002549 ms per lookup (that's an average time when doing 1,000,000 lookups.  For comparison an indexed lookup on the same `Map` takes about 0.000017 ms.  So you save about 0.002532 ms per lookup.  So, this is fractions of a millisecond.

```js
function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;
    
    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}


let m = new Map();

// populate the Map with objects that have a property that
// you have to do a brute force lookup on

function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min)
}

// keep all randoms here just so we can randomly get one
// to try to find (wouldn't normally do this)
// just for testing purposes
let allRandoms = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let r = rand(1, 1000000);
    m.set(i, {id: r});
    allRandoms.push(r);
}

// create a set of test lookups
// we do this ahead of time so it's not part of the timed
// section so we're only timing the actual brute force lookup
let numRuns = 1000000;
let lookupTests = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numRuns; i++) {
    lookupTests.push(allRandoms[rand(0, allRandoms.length)]);
}

let indexTests = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numRuns; i++) {
    indexTests.push(rand(0, allRandoms.length));
}

// function to brute force search the map to find one of the random items
function findObj(targetVal) {
    for (let [key, val] of m) {
        if (val.id === targetVal) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

let startTime = Date.now();
for (let i = 0; i < lookupTests.length; i++) {

  // get an id from the allRandoms to search for
  let found = findObj(lookupTests[i]);
  if (!found) {
      console.log("!!didn't find brute force target")
  }
}
let delta = Date.now() - startTime;
//console.log(`Total run time for ${addCommas(numRuns)} lookups: ${delta} ms`);
//console.log(`Avg run time per lookup: ${delta/numRuns} ms`);

// Now, see how fast the same number of indexed lookups are
let startTime2 = Date.now();
for (let i = 0; i < indexTests.length; i++) {
    let found = m.get(indexTests[i]);
    if (!found) {
        console.log("!!didn't find indexed target")
    }
}
let delta2 = Date.now() - startTime2;
//console.log(`Total run time for ${addCommas(numRuns)} lookups: ${delta2} ms`);
//console.log(`Avg run time per lookup: ${delta2/numRuns} ms`);

let results = `
Total run time for ${addCommas(numRuns)} brute force lookups: ${delta} ms<br>
Avg run time per brute force lookup: ${delta/numRuns} ms<br>
<hr>
Total run time for ${addCommas(numRuns)} indexed lookups: ${delta2} ms<br>
Avg run time per indexed lookup: ${delta2/numRuns} ms<br>
<hr>
Net savings of an indexed lookup is ${(delta - delta2)/numRuns} ms per lookup
`;
document.body.innerHTML = results;
```

Comment: Point taken. I was trying to do some forward-thinking. Someone else is also pointed out that; trying to solving a problem before having it doesn't make any sense. I just wanted not to encounter a problem in a production environment and catch fire.

Comment: @siniradam - See the last notes I added about encapsulation to give you ease of future modification and even ease of profiling this aspect of performance.  If you're really worried about this aspect of things, then it should be something you test at some simulated scale before you go to production.  Obviously, nobody wants any fires in production (that's one reason you do pre-testing), but fires are often somewhere other than the places we think they will be and the #1 issue often overshadows all the other things we've thought of.

Comment: I see, the thing is javascript engine's event loop time. I wanted to keep it short as much as possible. Additionally, I added missing important details to the user object. Since a single thread going to serve everyone, I wanted to keep lag sort.

Comment: @siniradam - Of course.  But, a brute force lookup  of a 1000 element `Map` is unlikely to be much of an issue as long as you're not doing it over and over and over again in the same request (if so, you need to fix the code that's looking up the same element over and over again).  If, after measuring things at scale or simulated scale, you find this is actually anywhere in the top 5 issues, then it's a simple addition to add a second optimized way of looking things up, but no point in over engineering until you actually have data that says you need the second mechanism.

Comment: @siniradam - See this little test script: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fhw0r6go/.  On my computer, it shows a brute force lookup in a 1000 element `Map` object takes about 0.0039 ms.

Comment: @siniradam - I updated my answer and the  jsFiddle script to show you a comparison between brute force lookups and indexed lookups.

Comment: wow, that is amazing. In my project, this loop essentially will gather information from each user object and will create a temporary list (a country list) and it will transmit this list to the corresponded operators. But this test shows me it is not even a thing.

Comment: @siniradam - Like I said, CPUs are really fast these days.  Unless you're doing some heavy computation, what usually takes the time is looking things up in databases or reading/writing files.

Comment: I tried to avoid using DB as much as possible. First-time connections and chat messages only are being saved in DB, therefore no chat no record. Although each time a user joined or left the list will be updated.